# Woocommerce REST API V2: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. Status ProtocolError

Tags: c#, wordpress, api, windows-services, woocommerce

I want to update order status through Woocommerce REST Api V2 in my windows service project. I got a sample C# code to download orders from this link

[Consuming WooCommerce REST API from C#](https://gist.github.com/jakobt/b7400463e90e16928f57)

Its working fine as I am downloading orders from my local server.
But I want to update order/add order note.

I tried this

```
    public string UpdateOrder()
    {
        //return MakeApiCall_mine("orders/17", new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "order", "{\"status\":\"completed\"}" } });//
        return MakeApiCall_mine("orders/17");
    }
    private string MakeApiCall_mine(string endpoint, Dictionary<string, string> parameters = null, string method = "PUT")
    {
        if (parameters == null)
        {
            parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }
        parameters["oauth_consumer_key"] = this.ConsumerKey;
        parameters["oauth_timestamp"] =
            DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)).TotalSeconds.ToString();
        parameters["oauth_timestamp"] = parameters["oauth_timestamp"].Substring(0,
            parameters["oauth_timestamp"].IndexOf("."));
        parameters["oauth_nonce"] = Hash(parameters["oauth_timestamp"]);
        parameters["oauth_signature_method"] = "HMAC-SHA256";
        parameters["oauth_signature"] = GenerateSignature(parameters, method, endpoint);
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var pair in parameters)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(pair.Key), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(pair.Value));
        }
        var url = this.ApiUrl + endpoint + "?" + sb.ToString().Substring(1).Replace("%5b", "%5B").Replace("%5d", "%5D");
        //var result = wc.DownloadString(url);
        wc.UploadString(url, "{\"order\":{\"status\":\"completed\"}}");

        //return result;
        return "";

    }
```

but getting error **The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized**

My woocommerce user Permissions:Read/Write.

Comment: I'm using it with the v1 api for testing and downloading only (for the moment). How did you manage to download the string without getting a 414 Request-URI Too Long.

Comment: I did not get any error **414 Request-URI Too Long**. As I am using latest woocommerce version, I changed API_ENDPOINT = "wc-api/v1/" to API_ENDPOINT = "wc-api/v2/". But I tried API_ENDPOINT = "wc-api/v1/" and it's also working. I have only 3 orders with single item each.

Comment: I created WoocommerceApiClient.cs in my project.[link](https://gist.github.com/jakobt/b7400463e90e16928f57). I am calling function from another class.  `WoocommerceApiClient client = new WoocommerceApiClient(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, StoreUrl, Isssl);                
                string orders= client.GetOrders();`
                  and i created a function GetOrders in my WoocommerceApiClient class      `public string GetOrders()
        {
            return MakeApiCall("orders");
        }`

Comment: Ok, with that in mind i go figure out myself tonight how to achieve that, I've already contacted my hosting provider for the 414, it seems a configuration issue with the provider. hopefully i can help you with your question after that.

Comment: I have already done same thing in Woocommerce using C# and API V2